# Delay on first call on DataReader.Read()

Tags: c#, performance, database-connection, odp.net

I have a ODP connection to my oracle database.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
whild (reader.Read())
{
    //...
}
```

In some situations the first call to `reader.Read()` take more than usual time (3 to 10 sectonds).

Next calls are ok. Not only next calls are ok but also most of the time closing the application and re-running it is ok too!

What parameters would affect the `reader.Read()` to take time more than usual?

**Update1:**
To clarify the situation consider this situations:

1. The application runs.
2. Lots of queries execute during the application.
3. User decides to run a report with a specific query to some tables
4. ExecureReader is called in a proer time.
5. Now it's time to read via reader. but it takes unusual time.
6. User runs application again.
7. It doesn't happen again.

I guess it was about some caching mechanism on database. But if it was database caching then the `ExecuteReader()` should have variant execution times.

Comment: Maybe you are in debug mode.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean by debug mode? Is there a setting somewhere? While debugging with VS2012 I found that the reason of performance problem is this line in my code.

Comment: How did you find out that you have a performance problem with this line? How have you measured it, what means _"In some situations"_, only the first time(maybe symobols are loading) or also in different situations?

Comment: @TimSchmelter simply by debugging line by line using F10. The only slow line was this! Only in some situations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've just updated the question in respect to your comments.